# Galaxy gear s2 - Launche android application on phone from Tizen Web Application

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, samsung-gear-s2

I'm trying to figure out how to send some kind of intent to open an application on the Android Device that is synced with my Tizen Wearable. Any tips about it?

I found this link. With this code I'm able to launch the Samsung Store. I need to launch Google Play. I already tried to replace the appid for: com.android.vending

https://developer.tizen.org/ko/forums/web-application-development/wearable-send-intent-phone?langswitch=ko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after alot of research and some "reverse engineering" in the Nike Tizen Application (which opens the Google Play Store) I was able to open differente applications.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var appid = "com.samsung.w-manager-service";
    var type = "phone";
    var url = "market://details?id=br.org.cesar.punchcardreminder";

    var extra_data = [
              new tizen.ApplicationControlData("msgId", ["mgr_install_host_app_req"]),
              new tizen.ApplicationControlData("type", [type]),
              new tizen.ApplicationControlData("deeplink", [url])];

    var appControl = new tizen.ApplicationControl(
               "http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/default",
               null,
               null,
               null,
               extra_data);

    var appControlReplyCallback = {
            onsuccess: function(data) {
                console.log("launchUrl reply success");
                console.log("success: data = " + JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            onfailure: function() {
                console.log("launchUrl reply failed");
            }
        };

    try {
        tizen.application.launchAppControl(
                 appControl,
                 appid,
                 function() { console.log("intentBorba", "launchUrl success"); },
                 function(err) { console.log("intentBorba", "launchUrl failed: " + err.message); },
                 appControlReplyCallback);
    }catch(err) {
        console.error("[launcher] " + err);
    }
};
```

It's kind of frustrating figure out that there is not directly documentation of a such simple feature when you're starting to develop in a new language. I hope that this answer helps some people.